# Do restaurants ever oak their wine glasses?

Tags: wine, restaurants

Some time ago I was at a dinner with an oenophile who ordered an expensive bottle of red wine.  After a few sips, he noted that it was very "oaky."  I thought it was excellent, but I didn't smell *any* significant wood flavors.  After some puzzling and nosing each others' glasses it became clear that his *glass* had an oak smell to it.

It wasn't long before the sommelier confirmed this and began tripping over herself to apologize and make up for what was obviously a contaminated glass.  Thinking back on it I'm wondering: is it plausible that the restaurant was intentionally "salting" wine glasses with some sort of wood flavoring?  Is this a known practice in the industry?

(Unless it was being stored in a working woodshop I'm having a hard time imagining how a fine wine glass in a restaurant would naturally acquire a notable oak flavor in the course of cleaning and storing.)

Comment: Was the oenophile trained at all? Could there have been confusion about "oak" (I'm thinking cleaning product residue or even cigarette smoke residue)?

Comment: @David - He's experienced, and I'm a super-taster with a notoriously keen nose.  I don't know if the claim was explicitly "oak."  I wouldn't claim to know the wood specie, but it was definitely an "aging barrel wood" nose.  Keep in mind I had a glass with the same wine in it, so we were able to pick out the difference imparted by the glass.  If both glasses had been similarly tainted, I would have just assumed it was part of the wine's profile.  He might have known enough to alert on the fact that the particular wine he chose should not have a strong wood component.

Comment: Then my bet would be that it was a previously used glass that wasn't washed properly and had some kind of residue (possibly whisky). I propose an experiment (and I'll try it myself in the coming days): put a half-measure of whisky in a wine glass, swirl, empty (drink). Leave to dry overnight, pour in a reasonably big & powerful red... smell. In any case I would be shocked if this was intentional. To pick a small nit, "supertasters" aren't necessarily "better" tasters -- that's almost entirely down to olfaction and training. We just are capable of detecting a couple chemicals others can't.

Comment: @David: You're right of course about the supertasting.  I don't know how to qualify my olfactory acuity (except perhaps as "notoriously keen" ;)  I like the experiment idea, and I suspect it will produce the effect we observed (especially with a quarter-cask Laphroaig I have on hand).  But keep in mind this was a red wine glass at a fine restaurant: Is it conceivable they would be serving whiskey neat in such a glass?

Comment: If it was strongly oaky, a better bet might be a Bourbon (virgin cask aging). There are many ways it could end up in a "wrong" glass: by customer request, or it could be used as a temporary vessel, or a staff member's surreptitious quaff with whatever was on hand. Who knows.

Answer (score 4):

Smoked drinks are all the rage right now. I bet something like this happened. Scroll down a bit. [Smoked whisky drink](http://www.frolichawaii.com/stories/something-new-downtowns-bar-leather-apron/)

[image]

Comment: Wow: That would certainly do it!  Although this was several years ago, and it was a red wine glass.

Comment: Who knows what drink they could've been making. I first saw this about 5 years ago but it just keeps getting more popular.